# Does Android 2.1 SDK support APIs for changing network settings?

Tags: android

I wish to know if Android 2.1 SDK support APIs for changing network settings such as bluetooth on/off, wifi on/off , airplane mode on/off. Thank you!

Comment: What about checking the official docs?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [official API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference), it seems that [bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#BLUETOOTH_ON) and [wifi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#WIFI_ON) settings are readonly, but [airplane](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON) mode can be set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enable/disable wifi with [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and Bluetooth with [`BluetoothAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html).  However, your app will need the associated permissions to change either of the settings.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies! 
Erich, what do you mean by associated permissions? I am kind of new in Android development. 
You mentioned WifiManager and BluetoothAdapter, what about enabling/disabling calling and sms functions? Basically i want to write a small app for my phone that blocks receiving calls and sms from certain numbers (Blacklist). Thanks guys!